# Not able to Update database while creating a custom module

Tags: plugin-development, errors

This is the php page through which i created the table , now i want to update the table. Not not able to do.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package wplab-campaign
 * @version 1.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Wplab Campaign

Description: Sinple Pluign to host capaign
Author: Saurabh Ranjan
Version: 1.0

*/


function my_plugin_create_db() {

    global $wpdb;
    $version = get_option( 'my_plugin_version', '1.0' );
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_analysis';

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        views smallint(5) NOT NULL,
        clicks smallint(5) NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );

    if ( version_compare( $version, '2.0' ) < 0 ) {
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
          id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
          views smallint(5) NOT NULL,
          clicks smallint(5) NOT NULL,
          blog_id smallint(5) NOT NULL,
          UNIQUE KEY id (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        dbDelta( $sql );

        update_option( 'my_plugin_version', '2.0' );

    }


}




function my_plugin_insert_db() {
   global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_analysis';
   $views = "1";
   $clicks = "1";
    $blog_id = "123s";

   $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'time' => current_time('mysql'), 'views' => $views, 'clicks' => $clicks, 'blog_id' =>$blog_id  ) );
}




function my_activation_func() {
    file_put_contents( __DIR__ . '/wplab-campaign-log.txt', ob_get_contents() );
}


register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_activation_func' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_create_db' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_insert_db' );
```

[image: missing coloumn]

`Note:` After saving the above page , I disabled the plugin and activated the plugin to see the changes , but nothing change even got below warning

`The plugin generated 585 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.`

Answer (score 0):

WordPress recommendations for the [`register_activation_hook`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook#Notes) hook are:

1. Don't do `echo` directly in the `register_activation_hook` callback function. Do it other hooks like [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) or [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init)
2. Make sure you are closing the PHP tag `?>`. Otherwise, you will get the `Header already sent notifications`.

I have tested your code, I think you are closing the PHP tag `?>` at the end of the file.

Comment: As you can see i am not using echo in my code and i checked my file i am not using ? >

Comment: Which version of WP are you using? Also, change hook of `my_activation_func ` function into `admin-init`.